# Coding the uniform probability density function

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution, density-function, python

In the chapter about the probability of Data Science from Scratch the author says:

> *the density function for the uniform distribution is just:*
>
> ```
> def uniform_pdf(x):
>     return 1 if x>= 0 and x <1 else 0
> ```

Whereas on Wikipedia, one can read that

> *The probability density function of the continuous uniform distribution is:*

$$f(x)={\begin{cases}{\frac {1}{b-a}}&\mathrm {for} \ a\leq x\leq b,\\[8pt]0&\mathrm {for} \ x<a\ \mathrm {or} \ x>b\end{cases}}$$

So shouldn't it be:

```
def uniform_pdf(x, a, b):
    return 1/(b - a) if x>= 0 and x <1 else 0
```

Here is the full excerpt:

[image]

Comment: The first definition is for the uniform distribution on the interval $[0,1]$.  I'd have made it $≤1$ myself, but whatever. Your proposed definition should be for $a≤x≤b$, not $[0,1]$.

Comment: from the excerpt,it looks like the author has defined the uniform distribution in such a way that it is supported on [0,1], presumably for pedagogical convenience